# How to liberate space in centos?

Tags: centos

my server 99% full disk folders would like to know I can remove without damaging my server.

the problem I have esque 30GB disk space and I have no idea as me to run out of space on my drive, my website only 1GB of space

Comment: It's your data. You decide what you want to destroy.

Comment: Yes, but the problem I have esque 30GB disk space and I have no idea as me to run out of space on my drive, my website only 1GB of space

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 30GB disk space and I have no idea as me to run out of space on my drive, my website only 1GB of space

Okay, here we go, something concrete.

First things first, go find what is taking up all your space. If you're not properly expiring old logs, they are a prime candidate for taking up too much space without being too beneficial. Check `/var/log/` or whatever else directories your might have configured to store your log files. (Some shared hosting environments may pick `~/httpd_logs/` or something similar. Look around.)

If you want to keep your old logs for analysis, compress them:

```
gzip -9 *.[1-9]
```

Many systems rotate logs through `access.log` to `access.log.0`, then move `.0` to `access.log.1`, then move `.1` to `access.log.2`, etc. So the above command compresses them all with `gzip(1)`'s highest compression level (plain text log files tend to compress really well). Then you can transfer them off your small storage hosting environment for analysis. Don't forget to *delete* them once you're done -- once you take them out of rotation, they'll never get cleaned up automatically.

Then go hunting for space more generally:

```
du -m | sort -n
```

The last line of this will represent the directory with the largest amount of stored data underneath it. Lines earlier in the output are less full. This output will show you which ones will give you the best improvements for your time. (This won't necessarily be the ones that you should delete, but getting rid of one needless one-gigabyte file is way more effective than getting rid of one hundred one-megabyte files.)

Comment: +1, partly for a good answer and partly because it felt wrong to leave you with a rep of 666. :) BTW, don't forget to check what's in /tmp.

Comment: @John: Good point about `/tmp`, I learned some bad habits from my first ISP that let anyone use `/tmp` without quota and the full knowledge that it might all go away any second. It only takes losing everything in `/tmp` on reboot _once_ to learn that those habits were mistakes. :)

Comment: I learned a slightly different lesson, cause by /tmp **not** being cleaned out periodically. :(

Comment: @John: hehe, also a lesson worth learning. Hope it didn't cause too much trouble.